# How to identify TOR packets?

Tags: tor, network-traffic

I am capturing network traffic using TCPDUMP with the following command:

```
TCPDUMP -i wlan0 -ttt port 9050 -w test.txt
```

How can I guarantee that all captured packet are TOR packets?

Comment: You don't. That's the whole point of TOR (well, since they released that module to disguise traffic - there are some identifying signatures of plain TOR traffic but I don't know what they are off the top of my head). Short of blocking all SSL (which will make many users very unhappy with you, I guarantee), you cannot.

Comment: So what I mean now is to find a way to know that certain packet is tor packet. one way to do it is to check whether the exit node ip is tor relay IP or not. the problem is where I can find the configuration file that contains the IP's of all tor relies.